# Wifi is connected ,but can't use Internet

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

My laptop shows that its connected but when i launch mozilla it doesn't load. When I use a wired connection it works. Any help?

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? You connect to a network over Wifi protected by a password? using Ubuntu 13.10? Which laptop do you use ?

Comment: HP Pavilion 17-e110dx

Comment: Im on the latest ubuntu release

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox edit preferences, go to the network section and set automatic proxy server. Does that work ?

Comment: No it did not, Thank you for responding though.

Comment: Can you ping the router and can you ping www.Google.com ?

Comment: This is my first time using linux so bare with me. I know how to ping google, but that doesn't work and I don't know how to ping my router.

Comment: OK. Your router will have an IP address. If your not sure what it is, connect via lan and in a terminal type ifconfig this will display your PC IP and gateway. Connect via WiFi again and try and ping the gateway IP. The gateway IP is the IP of your router.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: By the way, i've tried all the other answers on the forum about this problem

Comment: What didn't work ? The 'ifconfig' command ? Well what happened ? Try 'sudo ifconfig', note down the listed gateway.